# How to set initial interface orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, device-orientation

My application always launches in landscape mode with the home button on the left side. If the home button on the right side it rotates. How do i make it opposite? I tried setting different values into info.plist file for `initial interface orientation` key but it didn't work. I tried switching order of values in this method:

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

but it didn't work neither. How do i do that?

Comment: do you mean that the simulator is flipped ? Try using Command+Arrow Keys

Comment: what? simulator? orientation on device, not simulator

Comment: did you set the orientation on the view controller properly ? Is your iPad's orientation locked (the orange switch on the right of the device) ?

Comment: what? orange switch? what is it? and this is not iPad, this is iPhone

Comment: orange switch is the side switch ? :) @Luke what a strange name for a switch :)

Comment: It is just the color of it. But if he is using an iPhone, your answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IOS 5 and 5.1 :

Try to set `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your view controllers, it works for me.

[image]

[image]

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

If you are using storyboards you can also set your initial and other viewcontrolers to landscape mode :

[image]

For IOS 6:

your  `(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` should be `(NSUInteger)` , I am not sure though I never use it.

```
// Only used by iOS 6 and newer.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return TRUE;

}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{   
     //decide number of origination to supported by Viewcontroller.
     return return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;


}
```

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation never gets called. And if remove LandscapeLeft from Supported Interface Orientations, then my app never rotates whereas i want it to rotate.

Comment: well that means you are developing for IOS 6. and `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is for previous versions .

Comment: @AndreyChernukha how do you set your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: what do you mean? What is it "to set" rootviewcontroller? and btw, if in supportedInterfaceOrientations i will return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft then my app WILL ALWAYS BE in this orientation, which is not what i need. I need to change launch orientation and that's all

Comment: @AndreyChernukha then `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;`